# My DirectShow filter has no pins

Tags: c++, graph, directshow

I usually build filter graphs with GraphEdit.

I can add my filter correctly. This filter comes from a Driver made from WinDDK. It has one input pin and one output pin.

When I try to do it programatically using [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375815%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), the filter loads, but it has no pins. Pins enumeration fails and when I connect to my remote graph with graphedit, it doesn't show any pins.

How can I make sure that my driver exports the correct DirectShow filter?

What is the fundamental difference between the MSDN tutorial about creating DirectShow filters and GraphEdit "Insert Filter" function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have created your own source filter?

Point to double check:

- Did you implement GetPinCount, GetPin, FindPin correctly?
- Did you call IncrementPinVersion after adding/creating each pin?

I am not familiar with WinDDK development, but can you put breakpoints in those methods to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Some filters may have no pins (especially no **output** pins) when inserted to graph. These filters usually create their pins dynamically depending on certain conditions: for example, I know some BDA drivers that create their output pin only once their input pin have been connected.
This allow deciding the output pin's media type according to what will have been connected to the input pin.
Maybe you could check if you are not in a similar situation.

Gingko